# Laravel 5.8 in blade in @php directives not see variable from @foreach

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have problem with my code. I'm sending from controller to blade array with variables. After when I put array into foreach loop and try put variable from this array into another array (i'm doing this in @php directives) $val['id_proces'] is undefined.

```
    @foreach($risk as $ri)
        @foreach($tabela as $tab => $val)
            @if($ri->id_risk === $val['id_risk'])
                 @php
                   array_push($tab1, $val['id_proces']); // not see $val
                 @endphp
                @else
                 @php
                   $tab1 = array();
                 @endphp
                @endif
            @endforeach
```

I tried do this like this

```
{{array_push($tab1, $val['id_proces'])}}
```

But it's printing everything.

Comment: Try `@php print_r($val['id_proces']); @endphp` and see what it is printing.

Comment: Use normal php tags `<?php ...  ?>`

Comment: If i use tags <?php ... ?> then all arrays recived from controller is undefined.

Comment: Isn't your `$ri->id_risk === $val['id_risk']` validation resetting your array every time this is not true? Is this something you are looking forward to do?

Comment: I need this valdiation beacase I do not want all values from array.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is like this:

```
 @php $tab1 = []; @endphp

  @foreach($risk as $ri)

    @foreach($tabela as $tab => $val)

      @if($ri->id_risk === $val['id_risk'])

          @php array_push($tab1, $val['id_proces']); // not see $val  @endphp


        @else

     @php $tab1 = array(); @endphp

    @endif

@endforeach

@endforeach
```

#### Array vlaues are as bellow

```
@foreach($tab1 as $tabVal)

 {{ $tabVal }}

@endforeach
```

You can not print the array using  {{ }}. To display array you need to set a loop like this:
use

```
{{ dd($tab1) }}
```

to debug full array

Comment: I'm not sure that you understand where i have problem or I don't understand your answer :)

Comment: for error of undefined you can use like this
$val->id_proces or can print_r($val) and check the instence and value is set or not for all occurence of loop.

Comment: I understand that an array variable is not displaying. So I have given the example to access and set the array values to display. I hope it helps.